# How to paginate an ever updating feed that is ordered by date

Tags: mysql, pagination, infinite-scroll

I have a content feed, ordered by `date DESC, id DESC`.
`date` is just a date, not datetime.
`id` is a typical `INT auto_increment`.

I need to query for `n` rows that "come after a specific row". (imagine an infinite scroll which requires to "fetch items that are older than the current last item")

I would query for `where id < :last_id`, but the problem is that the order of `date` is not coherent with the one of `_id`.

I would query for `where date < :last_date`, but the problem is that there are more than 1 items "per day". I would lose all items that use the same date.

I would query for `ORDER BY date DESC, id DESC LIMIT x, n` but the feed could change between the 2 queries, adding new items to the top, and therefore shifting the whole offset.

My current hacky solution is to query for `where date <= :last_date ORDER BY LIMIT date DESC, id DESC LIMIT n+20` and then "manually" discarding the results that come before the current latest item. (hoping that there aren't more than 20).

I'm sure I'm not the first one to encounter a similar problem... Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have more than one item per day, then you should already have a secondary sort order. If it's id, then write your where clause like this:

```
WHERE date < :last_date OR (date = :last_date AND id < :last_id)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create a field where you store a Timestamp (+ on update current_timestamp?). I assume you don't get multiple entrys at one second. When you got a result, you save the latest timestamp, and in your next query you pass this to your script. Your query could change to:

```
SELECT * FROM [table] WHERE timestamp_field > [last timestamp] ORDER BY timestamp_field DESC
```